# Стили медиазапросов не перекрывают оригинальные стили

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, media-queries

В коде медиа запросы идут после основной части кода и следовательно - должны перекрывать указанные раннее параметры, но этого по какой-то причине не происходит. Разве что проблема решается через добавление `!important` после свойства, но это явно не самое правильно решение.

[image: Пример того самого перекрытия в отладчике]

Comment: Дело в специфичности селекторов. Селектор `.main_section .left-part .feedback_pages_wrapper .feedback_pages` более специфичен, чем `.feedback_pages` и имеет больший приоритет.  http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie

Comment: То есть, если правильно понимаю, то уровень "каскадности" в медиа запросах должен быть не меньше каскадности оригинального кода, верно?

Comment: Каскадность это маленько не то. Тут всё-таки уместнее "специфичность". Но в целом, да.